# What is the best way using Laravel to hide and show a particular div without using jquery to do this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a div that I would like to show when the button "See more Details" is clicked, I then would like to hide this when the button "See Less Details" is clicked.

What is the best way using **Laravel** to hide and show a particular div **without using jquery** to do this? Is there a similar way to accomplish this to how Angular does?

```
<div class="details"></div>
<a href="">See Less Details</a>
<a href="">See More Details</a>
```

Comment: Laravel is a PHP framework, PHP is a server-side language, and you need client-side processing, i.e. JavaScript, pure or not.

Comment: So I have a solution using jquery but the main problem is the entire page reloads instead of just that one div on the page

Comment: Your ask and its solution are not related with laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is inline version for it:

```
<div class="details" style="display:none">HIDDEN CONTENT</div>
<a id="more" href="#" onclick="$('.details').slideToggle(function(){$('#more').html($('.details').is(':visible')?'See Less Details':'See More Details');});">See More Details</a>
```

Check it out on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/103oc10s/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't make the page reload, which is good! But it does shift the page to the top everytime I click it... I'm wondering if this could be fixed to remain at the same level at the button itself

Comment: If you hide some content, the content below it will shift up, there is LOGICALLY no way around it, unless you want to make a static wrapper with defined height.

Comment: I actually figured it out! I had to get rid of the href="" part and it worked!

Comment: that was your problem :) there should not be href="", but href="#" (or href="#!"). If you got rid of href attribute entirely, your cursor will not change to cursor (hand) upon hovering upon your link. Also, this script will not work if you have several blocks like this on one page. If you insist on not having href attribute, you could add "curson: pointer" to your css.

Comment: Also, you should note, that if you will have many blocks like this on many pages, you should migrate that script inside <script></script> under ready method. I am more of "inline-oneliner" guy, hence the solution.

Comment: That's what I did and I just changed the <a> tag to a <div> I didn't need the href... the href="#" makes it load to the top and href="" makes the entire page reload

Comment: If you have null anchor in your href attribute and it scrolls to the top, it means you have some other error in your script.